# How to get rid of new empty chrome window that opens up while running in headless mode

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium/gauge automation project and using java for the code.  In my driver factory, I have it set to run headless, however; when I run it, an empty chrome window launches for some reason.  How can I make it stop launching this window?

public static WebDriver getDriver() {

```
    String browser = System.getenv("BROWSER");
    if (browser == null) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("chrome.switches","disable-extensions", "ignore-certificate-errors", "no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking"); //Global driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("headless");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

public class AppLauncher {

```
public static String APP_URL = System.getenv("APP_URL");

@Step("Launch Qualitrac")
public void launchQualitrac() {
    webDriver.get(AppLauncherObjects.getMapPageNames().get("Qualitrac"));
    assertEquals("Qualitrac", webDriver.getTitle());
}
```

}

public class Driver {

```
// Holds the WebDriver instance
public static WebDriver webDriver;
public static HashMap globalStash;

// Initialize a webDriver instance of required browser
// Since this does not have a significance in the application's business domain, the BeforeSuite hook is used to instantiate the webDriver
@BeforeSuite
public void initializeDriver() {
    webDriver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    globalStash = new HashMap<String,String>();
}

// Close the webDriver instance
@AfterSuite
public void closeDriver(){
    webDriver.quit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

could you replace :

```
options.addArguments("headless");
```

With :

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. Funny thing is that this was working fine up until last week. Not sure if chrome made an update and is causing the issue.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I needed to add another dependency in my pom file and now no extra windows pop up, just the one that it's executing on.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.50.0</version>
        </dependency>